# Reading In txt File and Extracting Elements from Input Problem

Tags: c, function

I have been attempting to fix this for hours. I am trying to read a file called wiktionary called "stuff.txt" which has input of the form:

```
10000
   5627187200   the
   3395006400   of
   2994418400   and
   2595609600   to
   1742063600   in
   ...
```

The 10000 represents the number of lines. I am then reading it in using a function `read_in_terms`, and extracting the number (weight) and the word (word) from it. I have tested my `get_word` and `get_weight` functions seperately and they seem to be working. However, when I am reading in, my `get_word` function is not returning the word .... the `get_weight` number is...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}

// from a string of the form "    29480398934  the" it returns number
long get_weight(char *string) {
    long length = strlen(string);
    char number[200];
    int count = 0;
    
    // Here I am cycling through until X__X combination
    // I only add to the number if it is not " "
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (string[i-1] != ' ' && string[i] == ' ' && string[i+1] == ' ' && string[i+1] != ' ') {
            break;
        } else if (string[i] != ' '){
            number[count] = string[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    number[count] = '\0';
    return atol(number); // converts it to a long and then returns
}

// from a string of the form "    453495834  word" it returns word
char * get_word(char* string) {
    long length = strlen(string);
    char word[200];
    int count = 0;
    
    // the double space detection only works once we reach a character
    // this becomes 1 once that happens, allowing us to proceed to the next part
    int blocker = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (string[i] != ' '){
            blocker++;
        }else if (blocker > 0 && string[i] == ' ' && string[i+1] == ' ') {
            int int_count = i+1;
            while (string[int_count] != '\0') {
                int_count++;
                word[count] = string[int_count];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    word[count] = '\0';
    
    // now I need to copy this string into malloc
    char *str = (char *)malloc(count*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(str, word);
    return str;
    
}


void read_in_terms(int *pnterms, char *filename) {
    char part1[] = "/Users/adammartinez/Desktop/";
    char* title = concat(part1,filename);
    
    FILE *fp = fopen(title, "r");
    
    char line[200];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
    int num_lines = atoi(line);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++){
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
        printf("%ld \n", get_weight(line));
        printf("%s \n", get_word(line)); // NOT RETURNING WORDS
     }
}
 
int main(void) {
    //char* test_str = "     547584758475  the";
    //printf("%s %ld", get_word(test_str), get_weight(test_str));
    int terms = 1000;
    int *pointer = &terms;
    read_in_terms(pointer, "stuff.txt");
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: I've downloaded, built, and run your program using your sample data and I get two output lines per input line: (1) the number (2) the string. So, I am unable to reproduce your problem. I'm running it under linux (vs. WinX--which is indicated by your `part1` directory prefix). The word output is prefixed by a space, so you're _not_ stripping that in `get_word`. I added a check of the `fopen` return value for `NULL` and a check on `fgets` for `NULL` to allow your [short] test file to work.

Comment: Since Giovanni and I are unable to reproduce the issue, the only thing I can think of is that, since you're on [AFAICT] WinX, could the `stuff.txt` file be some sort of "wide char" format text file? That might not get conveyed into the code block here. Does a hex dump of your input file show anything unusual?

Comment: This is strange I am trying to replicate your work. I am going to try to reformat the stuff.txt to see if that is an issue as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine on my computer. Please look at the output below and tell me if it's what you're looking for. I set part1 to "" and I changed the number of lines in stuff.txt to 5.

```
5627187200 
 the
 
3395006400 
 of
 
2994418400 
 and
 
2595609600 
 to
 
1742063600 
 in
```

Comment: Please don't post _images_ of code/output. And, especially _links_ to _images_ Please _edit_ your answer and post the output text [and/or whatever else] as text in a code block here.

Comment: This is the output I wanted. I made a new textfile of of 5 letters as you did with spacing at the start, and two spacings between the number and word, and it is working. It seems that the file is formatted in a way that I am not understanding.